# XPages theme not loading new CSS file

Tags: xpages

I recently added a reference to a new CSS file into the base theme that is widely used by our XPages applications. The base theme lives in a bespoke extension library on the server.

In initial testing, I could see that the new CSS file loaded correctly. However, when I tested on an existing application, the CSS file didn't load at first until I unchecked the "Use runtime optimized CSS" setting in xsp.properties. Once resource aggregation was turned off, the file loaded correctly. Turn it back on - no longer loads.

At first I figured it was a browser caching issue although forcing a hard reload didn't seem to work and opening the application on a browser I never normally use (IE Edge) still didn't load the correct files (even after explicitly clearing the cache).

Turning off resource aggregation does seem to resolve the problem - but this is obviously not ideal. So is there something I'm missing - another way to force the new CSS file and updated theme to load without turning off CSS optimization in each template?